Is it possible to use Curve_fit on several signal without a for loop?
I'm wondering if it is possible to make a curve fitting for a matrix directly without making a for loop
I would like to make the curve fitting directly on an array where each line is a signal to estimate. So at the end I would like to have popt as an array 2XN
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Qt5Agg')
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def affine(x, a, b) :
    return a*x + b


x = np.arange(0,100,10)

a = 10
b = -2
y = np.array([affine(x, a+i, b) + np.random.normal(0,20,x.shape) for i in range(10)]).T

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)

for i in range(10):
    a_est = 9
    b_est = -1
    popt, pov = curve_fit(affine, x, y[:,i], p0 = [a_est, b_est] )
    print(i, popt)

#optimisation without the for loop
popt, pov = curve_fit(affine, x, y, p0 = [a_est, b_est] )


Does this answer your question? Scipy curve_fit multiple series of data

No, in that case, the observation are the same and the user expect to have only one estimation made. In my case i would like to have one estimation by observation

@ymmx well that is not clear from the example code. Here you have n-times the same a and b but different random addons

At the end, you'll need some type of iteration.

Okay. I change the slope of each curve to fit

Is it a linear fit, like in the example, or do you need non-linear fitting?

The function I will use is a bi exponential
def doubleexpD(x, D, Ds, f):
return f * np.exp(-x * (D + Ds)) + (1 - f) * np.exp(-x * D)
